# Creating directives in real time with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have an XML document that looks like

```
<something>
  <something-else />
</something>
```

I'd like to insert this directly into an HTML document. There are certain rules as to what `<something>` elements look like (for instance, they should be `div`s of width `100px` with a black background and should expand upon clicking). Angular directives seem like a good way to deal with this - just make a `something` directive. The only problem is that the XML is loaded from a server, so I can't make the directive beforehand. I've tried just inserting the directive creation into the controller, but it (expectedly) doesn't work with this simple example:

```
$scope.makeTheDirective = function () {
    module.directive('dir', function () {
        return {
            replace: true,
            template: '<div style="background:black;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>',
            link: function () {
                console.log('making the directive');
            }
        }
    });

    $(document.body).append($compile('<dir>This is a test</dir>'));
}
```

with appropriate calling in the document. How can I make Angular recognize directives created after the app is loaded so that I can add `$compile`d HTML to the DOM?

Comment: There's a quotation mark and HTML 'error' in your code. Try using: ````'<div style="background:black;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>'````

Comment: @AndreM96 Thanks, I fixed it now. The code was correct at home though, and it's still not working.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to create a JSBin example for you. You also missed a ````)```` and a ````,```` ;)

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching those. Again, I had the right thing at home, but I still can't get the directive to work. Thanks in advance for the JSBin.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ejizeb/1/ Doesn't work, yet ;)